# Android using animation when change button margin

Tags: android, animation, button, margin

i use frame layout to contain a board of button.

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            wN, hN);
    // Add Margin to the LayoutParameters
    buttonLayoutParameters.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight,
            marginBottom);
    button.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParameters);
```

in game play the buttons can change the position to another position. at this time i had reused

```
buttonLayoutParameters.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight,
                marginBottom);
```

but i also want to add animation while the position is changing. i already try some translate animation but not success. please help me to solve it
thank you